# Загрузил приложение в google play, не отображаются карты google map api.

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте, Загрузил приложение в google play , каторая работает с google map api. К сожалению в приложении не отображаются карты. Как я понял в приложении есть дебажный ключ и релизный. Правильно ли я понимаю, дебажный ключ генерирует сам гугл с sha1, а релизный должен сгенерировать я с утилитой keytool ?

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема. Аутентификация на эмуляторе работает , а после публикации нет. Вот как добыть релизный ключ:
keytool -exportcert -alias алиас который указал при создании релизного апк -keystore D:\AndroidKeys\key.jks -list -v

Comment: Посмотри, тут подробно рассказывают. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCwt7FO9tD8&t=1062s